# org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication is not resolvd in Springboot 2.2.5 version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Eclipse is showing error on `SpringApplication` class, while `mvn clean install` building successfully.
I'm using java 1.8, Maven 3.3.6, Springboot 2.2.5.
below is the code.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoAppStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoAppStarter.class, args);

    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-test</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.demo.springboot.DemoAppStarter</start-class>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Show the exact error message please!

Comment: No error message, Eclipse is showing compilation error on SpringApplication.run(..) as it is not finding it in classpath.

Comment: Does this project build correctly on plain command line?

Comment: yes, `mvn clean install` is doing its job perfectly.

Comment: Try - right click on project -> Maven-> Update project -> then check "Force update of Snapshots/Releases" -> click ok : The reason for this error might be multiple version of the same is downloaded into your maven local repository folder. And if it still does not work, then try by adding below plugin in your pom.xml -->  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>